# Where do i have to code the model? (Spring MVC Template Project)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm feeling a bit stupid asking this but I don't really know where to put the code of the model. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your model classes wherever you like, but it's a fairly common practice to create packages specifically for these purposes, e.g. com.mydomain.myproject.controller and com.mydomain.myproject.model, so in the file system, src/com/mydomain/myproject/controller and src/com/mydomain/myproject/model

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using [STS (spring tool suite)](http://www.springsource.org/sts)? You will be able to create a new spring MVC template project. It also contains some spring MVC example that you can use to start your own project. Usually, each example contains a model, a view and a controller!

Comment: Also, while you're at it, take a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo)

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded STS and it works great